# Do photons and matter wavefunctions both reflect off of mirrors the same way?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

Does a photon reflect off a mirror in the same way a bosonic wavefunction does?
If they are different, what are the physical mechanisms that cause those differences?

Additionally is this the same for fermionic wavefunctions?

Comment: Please specify the following: are we talking about physical mirrors (like the one I have in my bathroom), or about idealized surfaces with (which?) boundary conditions?

Comment: An idealized mirror is fine. If you want a "real-life" example you could do it for a broadband dielectric mirror.  (and I guess you'd have photons of the same wavelength as the bosonic wavefunction)

Comment: It all depends on the idealization then, really. Among non-classical effects, for example, is the Casimir effect: if you choose two parallel plates with Dirichlet boundary condition for fields, attractive force arises between the plates. Also photons **are** bosons, so I am not sure what you meant by the first part of your question.